# Spinner is not working in Fragment on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

The spinner just doesn't work, I tried different versions of the code, but it didn't work in any of them

Can anyone help solve this problem?

`TransferFragment.kt`

```kotlin
    package com.example.hotel2.transfer
    
    class TransferFragment : Fragment(){
    
        private var _binding: FragmentTransferBinding? = null
        private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            _binding = FragmentTransferBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val view = binding.root
            return view
    
            val transfers = arrayOf<String>("Flowers", "Candies")
            val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> =
                ArrayAdapter<String>(activity?.applicationContext!!, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, transfers)
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            val spinner = binding.spinner
            spinner.adapter = adapter
            spinner.prompt = "Title"
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?,
                    position: Int, id: Long
                ) {
    
                }
    
                override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
            })
    
        }
    
        override fun onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView()
            _binding = null
        }
    }
```

`fragment_transfer.xml`

```kotlin
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".transfer.TransferFragment">
    
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"></Spinner>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

According to my guess, the problem is in `activity?.applicationContext!!`, but I do not understand how to solve it.

Comment: `The spinner just doesn't work,` what does this mean ? what does it do or not do ? have you used logs/breakpoints to debug your app ?

Comment: When I launch my app and click on it, nothing happens.
Yes, I used it, but I still do not understand why it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `onCreateView()` you have this statement as the 4th statement in the method:

```
return view
```

All the code after this statement doesn't get executed.

Interestingly enough, your IDE (Android Studio or whatever) should tell you that!

Comment: Exactly! I've been programming on Android for a year now, but I haven't noticed such a trifle. Thank you very much)
P.S. Android Studio does not report this)

Comment: Interesting that Android Studio doesn't complain about this. Usually the IDEs are really good about warning re: unreachable code.